# Remove characters from string in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column which contains number of months in string and int format. Need to convert it into just integers. (eg 12)

```py
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Term':["12"," ","12 Months","12months","12mthsb","12 *4months"]})
```

Output:

```py
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Term':["12","12","12","12","12"]})
```

Tried using `str.replace(r'\D', '')` and `str.replace(r'[^0-9]', '')` but then the row with just the number (i.e. 12) gets replaced by NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have int/float/str mix in the column

You can try to convert to str and then replace:

```
df1['someColumn'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\D', '')
```